# Rails: session variable is nil outside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have made method in rails controller which returns json with session variable:

```
def get_facebook_code
    render json: { code: session[:facebook_auth_code] }
end
```

When I paste link in browser `http://localhost:3000/credentials/facebook/code` it works fine - session variable returns

And session variable is null when I run request from Postman or from js code from third-party application:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://localhost:3000/credentials/facebook/code",
  success: function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
  },
});
```

I allow requests for `credentials/*` path with help of `rack-cors` gem

```
resource '/credentials/*', headers: :any, methods: [:get]
```

Comment: What surprises you? Unless you have some kind of auth mechanism and authenticated requests possible for that third party, you won't get anything from session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because by default rails stores sessions in cookies.

Somehow you have added that key 'facebook_auth_code' in your browser session. The same key is not available to postman/third party app requests because cookies are different.